# Selenium Webdriver - Capture URL in screenshot using Robot

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new 
Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("ScreenShot.jpg"));
```

This code will capture the screenshot of whatever is present on the desktop screen when test cases fail. But I need to take screenshot of chromedriver browser screen with URL. How can I capture the error scenario in selenium?

Comment: Write the current URL to an error log that accompanies the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Normal way to get screenshot

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

if you need failing scenario exits to capture a screen shot you can check this post [How to capture Server Error Pages using selenium Web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754172/1974369)

Comment: For taking screenshot using robot your window must be visible if not Robot won't help

Comment: Code only answers are not the best way to answer a question. Please add explanation around why this is the answer to the question. Also, your answer is in no way answering the question.

Comment: I think OP's question was on Robot Framework. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chrome driver appears to be an issue for fullsize screenshots.  You can see that people have written a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795458/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-full-website-screenshots-with-chromedriver-and-firefo)

Or you can reference the screenshot [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-take-full-page-screenshot-on-chrome-using-selenium)